# Gitflow, releases and bugs oh my

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm currently getting my head around gitflow and how releases work in terms of having them deployed to a test server for another team to test and find bugs.

Let's say I have a release version of 1.5 that contains a few small features.

The features are merged into the `develop` branch and I have now branched from `develop` to `release/1.5.0`.

This release branch is now deployed to our test server.

The testing team check the site against the tickets for the features and report back. They find a bug with one of the features.

Now, here is the issue I can see - if I fix the bug, where does that bugfix go? Should I fold it into `release/1.5.0` and re-deploy? Or does it get flagged in a new ticket, and added to a fix version of `release/1.5.1` to do in a weeks time?

With the later, it would mean that a release gets signed off with bugs intact until they can be addressed further down the road.

The former seems plausible, but then I was under the impression all bugs etc get folded into `develop`? Meaning `release/1.5.0` cannot be re-deployed unless you re-merged `develop` but that would then encapsulate other bug fixes and features?

All this comes from wanting to utilise JIRA releases, and I was unsure as to when you say a version is ready to be flagged as released and whether you can release it with bugs in tact, knowing they'll be fixed later on?

Do you fix bugs in a currently tested release until they are gone and then release the version?

I'd assume then when you back merge the release branch into develop, the bug fixes are in there also?

Comment: According to the [original post for git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) you should "fold" the bug into the release branch. I would then re-deploy, and update any tags you've made.

Comment: So PR the branch in the release branch, meaning the bug is fixed in release, and then ultimately fixed when the release is back merged into develop?

Comment: That sounds correct to me, if your system uses PRs.

Answer (score 0):

With git-flow:

- you *may* add bugfixes to the release branch. You may add them at the same time to a bugfix branch from develop, to merge them into develop ASAP not waiting for the release branch to be merged back.
- You *may* also create a feature-branch for the bugfix, merge that to develop, and merge that to the release branch, or also cherry-pick the bugfix commits.

I believe both adding a patch to the release branch as well as adding it to develop are important, but several options are valid, so you still need to compare options.